# Is it possible to keep the focus of selected/highlighted text as it is?

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

I am creating a simple wysiwyg editor by using a `react-contenteditable`.
Is it possible that if user has selected/highlighted some text inside the editor its **focus** must not get lost if clicked outside on any other input element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maintain focus on an input tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670277/maintain-focus-on-an-input-tag)

Comment: Thanks for the response @0leg but it didn't worked. i want to keep the focus of the highlighted text inside the content-editable and also able to type on other inputs.